# Как часто имеете дело с рассылками?

Tags: рассылка

Вопрос в двух частях!
 1. Как часто сами подписываетесь на разные рассылки?
 2. Для разработчиков. Какие трудности бывают при работе с рассылками?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Как часто сами подписываетесь на разные рассылки?

Скорее никогда. Если под этим не подразумевается галочка "получать уведомления об ответах на форуме" etc. Галочки "получать рассылки" во всяких EULA и прочем снимаю. Да и вообще, на кой чёрт нужны все эти рассылки, если у приличных ресурсов есть RSS/Atom, а неприличные - зачем они? Ресурсы в смысле.

> 1. Какие трудности бывают при работе с рассылками?

Криворукие программисты, кривой хостинг, недоадмины...

Comment: ... а также плохо работающие спам-фильтры!

Comment: Да-да. Но это компенсирует фильтр "удалять" в почтовом клиенте :)

Comment: Я и про получение ответов "по галочке" и может быть подписка на, что либо тематически интересное (например вакансии).

А RSS/Atom разве могут отправлять письма индивидуального характера (к примеру   отчетов о песональных счетах и т.п.)?

Comment: Отправлять ни RSS, ни Atom ничего не могут по определению. Но доступ к потокам может быть закрыт авторизацией, тогда видеть их можно будет только по логину-паролю.

А что касается рассылок, которые заказывает пользователь, то не совсем понятно, о каких именно проблемах идёт речь. Они могут быть на любом этапе, начиная с программиста, не читавшего RFC. А могут и не быть нигде.

Answer (score 1):

> Как часто сами подписываетесь на разные рассылки?

Никогда

> Какие трудности бывают при работе с рассылками?

Проблемы с отпиской от этих рассылок